# Qtranslate linux alternatives?

Tags: 18.04, alternative, translation

In Windows with [Qtranslate](https://quest-app.appspot.com/) you can select text from any program(ebook reader, pdf, doc etc.), press some shortkey and translate it. Are there any alternatives for Ubuntu/Linux? There a lot of extensions(like S3.Translator for Firefox) but they just translate something that's in the browser's tab.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/1077701/248158 https://askubuntu.com/a/1077701/248158 helps.

Comment: Maybe Qtrans https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1127419/
or stand-alone scripts assigned to keyboard shortcuts... but the howto is in Polish https://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?t=185375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also using Qtranslate when i was on Windows and missed it after switching to Linux. So i made a simple application for my own need. Hope it can help you too: https://github.com/yasirtug/ni-translate

Answer (score 1):

I got this solved by using [Vivaldi Browser](https://vivaldi.com), it's a very handy one with many customizable features (including translating selection).

I set a shortcut to translation from the settings, and now it's almost the same experience of that with QTranslate.

Answer (score -1):

Same Qtranslate you can try crow-traslation support for linux, https://github.com/crow-translate/crow-translate